# cin is getting values separated

Tags: c++, cin

i am working on XO game with c++ but i have a problem

```
cout<<"please enter the field number For O"<<endl;
cin.get(a);

if (a=='1')
    arr[0][0] = 'O';
else if (a=='2')
    arr[0][1] = 'O';
else if (a=='3')
    arr[0][2] = 'O';
else if (a=='4')
    arr[0][3] = 'O';
else if (a=='5')
    arr[0][4] = 'O';
else if (a=='6')
    arr[1][0] = 'O';
```

the problem here is when i try to enter a number bigger then 9, 
for example 15, 
the program reads it 1 and 5 so it applies two conditions at once, 
i tried to use 
get

```
cin.get(a);
```

but it gave me the same result

Comment: `int someInt; std::cin >> someInt;` ([`get`, or at least the version you are using, returns a single character](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get))

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: BoBTFish, this is works the problem was that i defined a as character , thank you

Comment: Just use cin>>a;

Answer (score 0):

When you just use "cin" it takes one character especially in the case of an integer. If you want it to take your whole input then consider using "getline(cin,a)" i think that will fix your problem.